# remembering last hovered li and default hovered li on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, html-lists

Ok so i have a UL and each of the li has a background colour of blue, when you hover over the li its background colour changes to yellow.

That all works great with CSS but i want the last hovered li to remain hovered when the mouse is no longer hovering over an li.

But thats not all id also like the first li to by default be hovered when the page loads, going to non hovered when you hover over another li.

since :hover only works when you hover over an object you can't use CSS so i guess it will need to be done using Javascript and Classes. Should it be done like a Javascript hover button, with the first li having an active class which is removed when you hover over another li?

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
<a href="#">
  <li><p class="item-number">1</p><p class="item-name">Option 1</p></li></a>
<a href="#">
  <li><p class="item-number">2</p><p class="item-name">Option 2</p></li></a>
<a href="#">
  <li><p class="item-number">3</p><p class="item-name">Option 3</p></li></a>
<a href="#">
  <li><p class="item-number">4</p><p class="item-name">Option 4</p></li></a>
<a href="#">
  <li><p class="item-number">5</p><p class="item-name">Option 5</p></li></a>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.menu li{
display:inline-block;
height:5vh;
width:80%;
background-color:#003399;
color:#FFF;
margin-bottom:2px;
}

ul.menu li:hover{
background-color:#fed928;
color:#003399;
}
```

Comment: Please include your current code

Comment: If I was you, I'd use some kind of server-side stuff to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question.  Since you want this to persist over page loads, you'll definitely have to use javascript or somesuch to write to a cookie or a session.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript simply you can use JQuery and this code:

```
$("ul li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#EEE").siblings("li").css("background-color", "");
});
```

For include jquery in your code use this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

in your html code

If you need to remember last hover li in next page reload you can use Cookie and read [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)